# Accidentally Deleted Azure Multi-factor Auth client Service principal via powershell, how to restore it?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

Accidentally Deleted Azure Multi-factor Auth client Service principal via power shell, how to restore it?

Comment: -->I tried to create service principal again with new-azureadservicipal did not work.
-->Tried restoring with restore-azureadapplication did not work.

Comment: Which one? The one for the NPS extension?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to run the [PowerShell script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-nps-extension#run-the-powershell-script) to restore it, the PowerShell script was created when you installed NPS extension for Azure MFA.

Comment: I tried running this script earlier but it was giving me service principal not found error.

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-AzureADServicePrincipal | Where-Object { $_.appid -match '981f26a1-7f43-403b-a875-f8b09b8cd720' }  # did not show Azure Multi-factor auth client in list.

created new service principal for Azure Multi-factor auth client from below command.

new-AzureADServicePrincipal -AppId 981f26a1-7f43-403b-a875-f8b09b8cd720

set-AzureADServicePrincipal -AppId 981f26a1-7f43-403b-a875-f8b09b8cd720 -ObjectId  b9ffe563-20b2-4ada-98f0-665cd878581c -AccountEnabled $true  # object id obtained from above command
```

Now I am able to view the service principal when I search with object ID.

Comment: Okay. If there is anything update, please let me know, thanks!